# Custom EventTrigger to use RoutedEvent for animation

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, animation, eventtrigger

This is what I'm trying to accomplish.

It's a barcode reader for a kiosk.

- main screen textBlock should say "Scan barcode"
- after Barcode Read
- Connect to a remote SQL Server to check if Barcode qualifies
- If it qualifies main textBlock should say "you have won....." for 1 minute and show button to print winning.
- If it doesn't qualify it should say for 5 seconds "please check with the cashier"
- if its a wrong barcode it should say for 5 seconds "wrong barcode, try again"
- it should always revert back at the end to "Scan barcode"

I understand it would be best to do an animation on the textblock but then how do I trigger the animation from code.

It might be much an easier way to accomplish this, please let me know if there is.

I write code in VB, yea old school, But I can easily convert your C# code online.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would use the TextChanged event so an example would be something like.

```
    private void txScanBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            //Do whatever
    return;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm using this, let me know if you have a better approach.

in xaml I created 3 storybaords with no triggers.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="WrongBarcode">
        <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" Storyboard.TargetName="txtbScan">
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Wrong Barcode"/>
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="Scan your barcode"/>
        </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Win">
        <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" Storyboard.TargetName="txtbScan">
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Hurray You Won"/>
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:25" Value="Scan your barcode"/>
        </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Unqulified">
        <StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)" Storyboard.TargetName="txtbScan">
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Please Qualify your card at the Cashier."/>
            <DiscreteStringKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="Scan your barcode"/>
        </StringAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

and then in the code behind

```
Private Sub Window_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    Static curBarcode As String
    If e.Key = 6 Then 'Found that it hits key6 at the end of each barcode read
        Select Case ValidateCard(curBarcode)
            Case 0
                Dim Unqulified As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("Unqulified"), Storyboard)
                Unqulified.Begin(Me)
            Case 1
                Dim win As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("Win"), Storyboard)
                win.Begin(Me)
            Case Else
                Dim WrongBarcode As Storyboard = DirectCast(FindResource("WrongBarcode"), Storyboard)
                WrongBarcode.Begin(Me)

        End Select

        'txtbScan.Text = "Scan your gift card."
        curBarcode = ""
    Else
        curBarcode = curBarcode & Mid(e.Key.ToString(), 2, 1)
        '


    End If
End Sub
```

I still need to change the winning text, which has many variations. I'm thinking of adding a larger text block and maybe even an image and set the value in code and animate visibility.

Please let me know what you think.

Thanks